# AvCapture Session full screen in iphone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, avcapturesession

I am developing with AvCapture session to add cutom overlays on camera screen. I have added an AvCaptureVidePreview layer as

```
AvCaptureVideoPreviewLayer*layer = [[AvCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] iniWithSession:session];
layer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
```

but the camera preview is not full screen in case of iPhone 4S. It works fine in iPhone 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CGRect bounds=view.layer.bounds;
layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
layer.bounds=bounds;
layer.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
```

may be it can help you..